# Difference between pair in scheme and tuple in python?

Tags: python, scheme

In Scheme, if you have a list of pairs, like :

`((4 . 7) (4 . 9))`

isn't this basically a list of 2 element tuples? So if you were to write this in python, would it be like:

`[[4, 7], [4,9]]` or `[(4, 7), (4,9)]`?

I want it to be as close as possible to python. Or would creating a class be even closer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Scheme terms it does not make sense to refer to pairs as two-element tuples because that would imply that there's such a thing as a three-element tuple or a four-element tuple in Scheme, but there's not.

That said the closest Python concept to a Scheme pair would indeed be a two-element tuple. A list of pairs is definitely not the same as a list of lists.

Oh and to answer the question you implied in your title:

In Scheme a list is either the empty list (`()`) or a pair whose second element is a list. So every list is a pair, but some pairs aren't list. For example the pair `(1 . (2 . ()))` is a list (more commonly written as `(1 2)`), but the pair `(1 . 2)` is not a list because `2` is not a list.

None of this applies to Python. Python lists are growable arrays - not linked lists made out of pairs/tuples.

Answer (score 0):

there are many differences in scheme(pair) and python(tuple), like tuple are immutable while others are not, pair returns 0 when its not a pair but tuple can stand with one value (x,) and many more..

read: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm (for python)
      http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Pairs.html (for Scheme)

:)